# Most efficient method of find a solution - C++

Tags: c++, performance, encryption

I've been learning C++ for the past few weeks and have been given a task to do. I've had a go at this task and wondered whether anyone would be able to point me in the right direction in terms of making my code more efficient and straight forward.

Here's the brief of the task:

Look at the following partial PDL program that reads a (three-digit) integer representing the value to be encrypted, a (one-digit) integer representing the encryption key, encrypt the value and print the encrypted value. The encrypting method used is that each digit in the given number is replaced by ((the sum of that digit plus key) modulo 10) then the first and last “encrypted” digits are swapped.

`produceEncryptedNumber
    output( "Enter the original three-digit number: ")
    input( originalNumber)  //read in a (three-digit) number
    output( "Enter the key: ")
    input( key)                 //read in a (one-digit) number
    call isolateDigits          //find out the 3 digits that make up the number
    call replaceDigits          //’encrypt’ each of the three digits
    call swapDigit1WithDigit3   //swap first and last digit
    call recomposeEncryptedNumber   //recreate encrypted number from ‘encrypted’ values
                            //output encrypted number
    output( "The encrypted number for ", originalNumber, " is ", encryptedNumber, ".")`

For example, if the number entered was 216 and the key given was 7, after applying the encryption procedure described the first digit (2) would become 9, the middle digit (1) would become 8 and the last digit (6) would become 3. The first and last encrypted digits are then swapped. The program displays the encrypted number: that is 389 in this case.

Examples of how the program should appear in a command window (with expected returns):

`Enter the original three-digit number: 216
Enter the key: 7
The encrypted number for 216 is 389.`

`Enter the original three-digit number: 123
Enter the key: 7
The encrypted number for 123 is 098`

And here is my code for the solution:

`
    #include

```
using namespace std;

// Global Variables 
int originalNumber, key, a, b, c, number, valA, valB, valC, encryptedNumber;

// Main Section of the Program
int main()

{
    // Get original Number
    cout << ("\nEnter the original three-digit number: ");
    cin >> originalNumber;

    // Get Key
    cout << ("\nEnter the key: ");
    cin >> key;

    // Call isolateDigits
    void isolateDigits();
    isolateDigits();

    // Call replaceDigits
    void replaceDigits();
    replaceDigits();

    // Call swapDigit1WithDigit3
    void swapDigit1WithDigit3();
    swapDigit1WithDigit3();

    // Call recomposeEncryptedNumber
    void recomposeEncryptedNumber();
    recomposeEncryptedNumber();

    // Check for a 3-digit outcome and print out the original + final values

    // If the value of the outcome is more than 2-digits and less than 3-digits, then add a single 0 at the front of the output.
    if (encryptedNumber >= 9 && encryptedNumber <= 99)
        cout << "\nThe encrypted number for " << originalNumber << " is 0" << encryptedNumber << ".\n\n";

    // If the value of the outcome is less than 2-digits, then add two 00's at the front of the output.
    else if (encryptedNumber <= 9)
        cout << "\nThe encrypted number for " << originalNumber << " is 00" << encryptedNumber << ".\n\n";

    // If the value is 3-digits exactly then simply output the value in the normal order. 
    else
        cout << "\nThe encrypted number for " << originalNumber << " is " << encryptedNumber << ".\n\n";

    // Pause at end
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}

// isolateDigits procedure
void isolateDigits()
{
    a = originalNumber / 100 % 10;
    b = originalNumber / 10 % 10;
    c = originalNumber % 10;
}

// replaceDigits procedure for Encryption
void replaceDigits()
{
    valA = a + key;
    valB = b + key;
    valC = c + key;
}

// swapDigit1WithDigit3 procedure
void swapDigit1WithDigit3()
{
    valC = a + key;
    valB = b + key;
    valA = c + key;
}

// recomposeEncryptedNumber procedure
void recomposeEncryptedNumber()
{
    // Check for values above 2-digits
    if (valA >= 10)
        valA = valA - 10;
    if (valB >= 10)
        valB = valB - 10;
    if (valC >= 10)
        valC = valC - 10;

    // Put the values together
    encryptedNumber = 100 * valA + 10 * valB + valC;
}
```

`

Any tips on how to improve this solution is greatly appreciated, I'm always keen to learn new things and please go easy on me, I'm still fairly new to programming in C++. Thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Though first re-format it properly. Hint: `<!-- language: none -->` disables syntax-highlighting for the next code-block.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code and giving suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright Boris,

- Move your encryption code into it's own class
- Gather the steps into a single, encrypt function
- Replace Digits actually doesn't do any useful work in your current solution

Might I suggest that you start with the following declaration of an Encryptor class and go from there:

```
class Encryptor
{
 Public:
  Encryptor();
  ~Encryptor();

  void setKey(int key);
  unsigned int encryptNumber(unsigned int number);

 Private:
  void isolateDigits();
  void replaceDigits();
  void swapDigits();
  void recomposeNumber();

  unsigned int a,b,c;
  unsigned int number;
  unsigned int key;
};
```

I'm suggesting the use of unsigned integers because your printing statements won't actually work for negative integers.

As a hint, replaceDigits would look something like:

```
void Encryptor::replaceDigits()
{
  a += key;
  b += key;
  c += key;
}
```